# Is it possible to specify a no-proxy parameter with conjure-up?

Tags: juju, proxy, conjure-up

I try to deploy Openstack on LXD using conjure-up. I'm behind a proxy server and during the start of conjure-up I provide the switches for apt-proxy, apt-https-proxy, http-proxy and https-proxy. However, the intial part where juju is bootstraped already fails since it tries to use the proxy server for connections to the LXD network. I can't find a way to exclude the IP's for the LXD network for the proxy server with conjure-up. Exporting no-proxy to the environment has no impact.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed over at https://github.com/ubuntu/conjure-up/issues/171 and you can expect to have this option in the next prerelease (due out July 5th).